# How to get rich text response dialogflow php api

Tags: php, dialogflow-es

hello I am trying to get rich text response from dialogflow using php api 
my sample code

```
$session = $sessionsClient->sessionName('agentId', $sessionId ?: uniqid());
$textInput = new TextInput();
$textInput->setText('question');
$textInput->setLanguageCode('en-US');

$queryInput = new QueryInput();
$queryInput->setText($textInput);

$response = $sessionsClient->detectIntent($session, $queryInput);
$queryResult = $response->getQueryResult();
$fulfilmentText = $queryResult->getFulfillmentText();
echo fulfilmentText;
$sessionsClient->close();
```

above code works fine but when i replace `$fulfilmentText = $queryResult->getFulfillmentText();` with `$fulfillmentMessages = $queryResult->getFulfillmentMessages();` and when i print i get error as

> Object of class Google\Protobuf\Internal\RepeatedField could not be
>   converted to string

any input will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default response, there is **NO** rich text!
Rich Text response is for other channels (Facebook messenger, Skype ...)

You can use something like this:

```
$fulfilmentMessages = $queryResult->getFulfillmentMessages();
$output = [];
foreach ($fulfilmentMessages as $number => $message) {
    switch ($message->getMessage()) {
        case 'text':
            $output[] = ['text' => $message->getText()->getText()->offsetGet(0)];
            break; 
        case 'card':
            $card = $message->getCard();
            $buttons = [];
            foreach ($card->getButtons() as $button) {
                 $buttons[] = [
                     'text' => $button->getText(),
                     'postback' => $button->getPostback()
                 ];
             }
             $output[] = ['card' => [
                'title' => $card->getTitle(),
                'subtitle' => $card->getSubTitle(),
                'image' => $card->getImageUri(),
                'buttons' => $buttons
             ]];
             break;
      }
}
```

**$output** will contain an array with normal text plus rich text responses. You need to make a nice custom view for it.